# how to sum 2 numbers in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this properties

```
export interface IOurFirstSpfWebPartWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  n1: number;
  n2: number;

}
```

Then I have this method

```
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${styles.ourFirstSpfWebPart}">
        <div class="${styles.container}">
          <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}">
            <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-u-lg10 ms-u-xl8 ms-u-xlPush2 ms-u-lgPush1">
              <span class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">${this.properties.n1} + ${this.properties.n2}</p>
              <a href="https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki" class="ms-Button ${styles.button}">
                <span class="ms-Button-label">Learn more</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`;
  }
```

However this is printing 1+2 instead of 3.

Comment: Because + also works as a concatenation operator and that's what seems to be done in your code.So its printing 1+2 and not 3. instead try adding your expression in curly braces it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answer is related to implicit coercion in javascript. Simply put, you're concatinating two strings in a template and not adding two numbers.

When you hit the `{}`s in your templating syntax, your numbers will be stringified. In essence you are then adding

> "1" + "2" = "12"

instead of

> 1 + 2 = 3

You can try two things:

1. put both expressions inside of the {}

> `${this.properties.n1 + this.properties.n2}`

If that still makes "12" then

2. Try `${parseInt(this.properties.n1) + parseint(this.properties.n2)}`. That will coerce both values to a number first, if it can be done.

You can learn more about type coercion in the article *[You Don't Know JS: Types & Grammar](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)*, where it will really explain all the 'gotchas' out there about the + operator and implicit types.

Answer (score 15):

Add an extra `+`, for every argument which you want to add. You need to do it like: `this.sum =  +this.num1  +   +this.num2;`.

Comment: @JohanMorales Nice to hear that. Its motivating for me

Answer (score 2):

The tick mark creates a template literal. I think you're looking for:
`${this.properties.n1 + this.properties.n2}`—all inside the same curly braces.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: still concatenating... :(, properties are defined as numbers

Comment: I suppose you could wrap the properties in Number.parseInt(): `Number.parseInt(foo) + Number.parseInt(bar)`

Comment: @LuisValencia-MVP are you sure you've actually updated code - I'd recommend starting with [MCVE] like `function f(){
var x = 3;
console.log(\`test ${x}+${x}=${x + x} \`);}; f();` in your browser console...

Answer (score 1):

prepend the numbers with a + sign